# JQuery Time Spinner Icon Color

Tags: jquery, css, icons

I am trying to use alternate color icons for ui-icon-triangle-1-s and ui-icon-triangle-1-n.

I downloaded ui-icons_6495ED_256x240.png

I have added the following to the CSS:

```
.ui-spinner-button .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(../images/ui-icons_6495ED_256x240.png);
}
```

Sadly, the arrows are still black :(

Answer (score 0):

Revised CSS as follows...

```
.ui-icon
{
  color: #00F;
}
```